# Use mod function in a constraint using Python Pulp

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am writing a LpProblem and  I need to create a constraint where the sum of some variables is multiples of 100... 100, 200, 300...

I am trying the next expressions using mod(), round() and int() but none works because they don't support LpAffineExpression.

probl += lpSum([vars[h] for h in varSKU if h[2] == b]) % 100 == 0

probl += lpSum([vars[h] for h in varSKU if h[2] == b]) / 100 == int(lpSum([vars[h] for h in varSKU if h[2] == b]) / 100)

probl += lpSum([vars[h] for h in varSKU if h[2] == b]) / 100 == round(lpSum([vars[h] for h in varSKU if h[2] == b]) / 100)

Can you give me some ideas for write this constraint.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly simple approach:

- introduce an integer-variable `I`
- build your constraint as: `probl += lpSum([vars[h] for h in varSKU if h[2] == b]) == I*100`
- (constrain `I` as needed: e.g. `I >= 1`; `I <= N`)

Keep in mind: when having multiple constraints and the multiples of 100 are not necessarily the same for your constraints, you will need one auxiliary variable `I_x` for each constraint!

(And: you can't use python's operators *in general* within pulp or any other LP-modelling sytem (round, int, mod, ceil, ...)! You have to accept the rules/form those modelling-systems allow: in this case -> `LpAffineExpression`)

Comment: Where should the integer - variable `I` be placed in the objective function of the model `probl`?