# How to constrain the subject to rounded integer using Python Pulp

Tags: python, rounding, pulp

I'm using pulp for a linear optimization problem. I want the subject to be rounded to 100. How should I do it.

I saw the answer to this one, But I don't know how to defined a integer variable I in this case. 
[Use mod function in a constraint using Python Pulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929215/use-mod-function-in-a-constraint-using-python-pulp/56583868#56583868)

Thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'rounded to 100'? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Like I want results be 100 multiplier, if it returns 90 I wanted to be 100

Comment: Can you share the code snippet and share where it causes the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple ILP which consist of an objective function and constraints on the variables:

```
min x1 + x2
s.t.
x1 + x2 >= 50
x1 >= 0 
x2 >= 0
```

To enforce your condition you can add 2 variables `y` and `z` and 2 constraints:

1. `y >= x1 + x2`
2. `y == 100 * j` for some `j >= 1`

and change your objective function in `min y`.

In code:

## Original formulation

```
x1 = pulp.LpVariable('x1',lowBound=0,cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
x2 = pulp.LpVariable('x2',lowBound=0,cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

prob1 = pulp.LpProblem('example1',pulp.LpMinimize)
# obj
prob1+= 5*x1 + 10*x2
# constraints
prob1+= x1 + x2 >= 50

prob1.solve() 
print(pulp.value(prob1.objective)) #250
```

## Converted one

```
y = pulp.LpVariable('y',lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
z = pulp.LpVariable('z',lowBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

prob2 = pulp.LpProblem('example2',pulp.LpMinimize)
# obj
prob2+= y
# constraints
prob2+= y >= 5*x1 + 10*x2
prob2+= y == 100 * z
prob2+= x1 + x2 >= 50

prob2.solve()
print(pulp.value(prob2.objective)) #300
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also take a look at this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949190/how-to-apply-conditional-constraints-to-python-pulp-function

Comment: What would be the approach for applying a condition that each LP variable should be a multiple of 100? I am trying to solve a supply chain problem where the quantity of each part (i.e. LP variable) should be multiple of 100. Kindly help